# Are we guaranteed a Lie group by taking the algebraic closure of finitely many one-parameter groups acting (each periodically) on a Euclidean space?

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups, lie-algebras

We are given a Euclidean space $E$ and a finite subset $\{A_{1}, \ldots, A_{k}\}$ of $GL(E)$.  Consider the one-parameter groups $g_{k}^{t} : t \mapsto e^{t A_{k}}$.  The operators $A_{k}$ are such that:

1. Each $g_{k}^{t}$ preserves the Euclidean norm.
2. The action of each $g_{k}^{t}$ on each $x \in E$ is periodic: there exists a positive time $T$ (dependent on $k$ and on $x$) such that $g_{k}^{t + T}x = g_{k}^{t} x$.

Since the groups $g_{k}^{t}$ are subgroups of $GL(E)$, so is the group, $G$, generated by their union.  Are we guaranteed that $G$ is Lie and that the orbit $Gx$ of an $x \in E$ under the action of $G$ is a submanifold of $E$?  If so, am I correct in thinking that the dimension of this manifold equals the dimension of the image of $x$ under the Lie algebra of $G$?  Any sources to study would be appreciated as well.

Comment: I think you mean to write $g_k^{t+T}x=g_k^tx$?

Comment: You probably mean that each $\exp({\mathbb R}A_i)$ is a compact subgroup. One can prove that $G$ is an immersed Lie subgroup; in general, it is noncompact and its orbits will be injectivly immersed submanifolds. I do not see a reason for these to be submanifolds.

Comment: In any case: I'm not sure why the algebraic closure of this union is a subgroup, but, if it is, then it's Lie; every closed subgroup is a Lie subgroup.

Comment: @Cronus In general, if $H_1, \ldots, H_{k}$ are subgroups of a group $G$, isn't the algebraic closure of the union $\cup_{i} H_{i}$ the smallest subgroup of $G$ that contains this union, by definition?

Comment: @avs Hmmm I think the way you're using the term "algebraic closure" is nonstandard. I thought you meant the closure in the Zariski topology, but now I guess you mean the group generated by $H_1,...,H_k$. In this case you can ignore my remark.

Comment: The group generated by a set of connected subgroup is connected, and therefore it is an immersed Lie subgroup, but I would guess it might not be closed.